# "All-forgiving" expressed with the omni- prefix

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, word-request

The English language has a handful of words starting with *omni-* to express *all-*:

- *omniscient* all-knowing
- *omnipotent* all-powerful
- *omnipresent* present everywhere

How would one express *all-forgiving* using *omni-*?

(I am not sure which word to use for *forgive*, but please assume a theological context.)

---

I am aware that it is possible that no word with this precise meaning appears in any English dictionary under *omni-*. However, the earliest words of the form *omni-* were modified versions of Medieval Latin terms, brought into English at some point by a person with knowledge of Latin. My question is: if the scholar who brought the word *omniscient* into the English language, were to have imported a word with the prefix *omni-* into English with the meaning *all-forgiving*, what choice would he have made, if you were to speculate?

One reason I ask here is that there are a great many ways to say *to forgive* in Latin. Some of them look as though they also mean *to dismiss, to send away*. I would like to know which is most appropriate and least ambiguous, if that can be determined.

If this still seems like a question about English rather than Latin, then assume my question is: **How would *all-forgiving* be expressed in Medieval Latin, in a theological context?**

Comment: Welcome to [latin.SE]! By reading your question I see a couple of different ways to answer it. My first thought is it's about English language, and thus you may want to ask at [english.SE] to get a better answer. As far as I know, there is no such word in English. A close miss may be _omnibenevolent_ (i.e., all-good willing, 69k results in Google: not a too common word, but with some usage). _Thelogical_ Latin for _to forgive_ is _dimitto_, so if you want to make an English word up, it could be omnidimittent (although I'm not sure if there is any other word in English derived from that verb).

Comment: If you want to know how to say it in Latin, with quotes to attested examples and links to dictionary entries, then this is the place. Please make us know.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain a little better.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this is helpful.  It looks like you've created two accounts, however – I'd recommend [merging them following these instructions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), to more easily track your question.

Comment: @AndrewWoods Although _dimitto_ has different meanings in Classical Latin, it is _the_ (overwhelmingly preferred) word both the Vulgate and Theologians use to mean _to forgive_. E.g. _dimittuntur peccata tua_ (Mc 2,5), _dimittuntur_ tibi _peccata tua_ (Lc 5, 23), _dimittite et dimittemini_ (Lc 6, 37). _Remitto_ is also used.

Comment: *Omniclement* is the short and simple answer.

Answer (score 12):

I found two examples (from [1667](https://books.google.com/books?id=XjhpAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA8&lpg=RA1-PA8&dq=omnimisericors&source=bl&ots=PkLPLNbYEU&sig=_l7qgwoT-jEqxfyEsZ3_-ijlkBo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO2qzuwNrPAhVDdj4KHT8FD1sQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=omnimisericors&f=false) and [1709](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfllAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=omnimisericors&source=bl&ots=NkdtSuENIh&sig=-6JvPJc3PK51i_y44ybxnAhlfPo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO2qzuwNrPAhVDdj4KHT8FD1sQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=omnimisericors&f=false)) that uses the first portmanteau that came to my mind: *omnimisericors*.

> ...laudo, adoro, & revereor te, Domine DEUS, Omnipotens, **Omnimisericors**, qui aquarum fontes creasti, etc...

This is obviously *not* standard.

The much more common way of saying "most merciful" in liturgical Latin is *clementissimus*.

There is a reason why *omni-* is generally not paired with attributes like this: in the scholastic tradition, as exemplified for instance by Aquinas's *Summa Contra Gentiles*, the *omni-* attributes are derived in a specific logical order and for specific reasons. Omni- is used with *perfections*, whereas *mercy* is more properly a passion which is applied in a metaphorical way, of his attributes. From the [*Summa Contra Gentiles*](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/ContraGentiles1.htm):

> Sciendum tamen etiam **alias affectiones**, quae secundum speciem suam divinae perfectioni repugnant, in sacra Scriptura **de Deo dici, non quidem proprie, ut probatum est, sed metaphorice, propter similitudinem vel effectuum**, vel alicuius affectionis praecedentis.
>
> Dico autem effectuum, quia interdum voluntas ex sapientiae ordine in illum effectum tendit in quem aliquis ex passione defectiva inclinatur: iudex enim ex iustitia punit, sicut et iratus ex ira. Dicitur igitur aliquando Deus iratus, inquantum ex ordine suae sapientiae aliquem vult punire: secundum illud Psalmi: cum exarserit in brevi ira eius. **Misericors vero dicitur inquantum ex sua benevolentia miserias hominum tollit: sicut et nos propter misericordiae passionem facimus idem.** Unde in Psalmo: miserator et misericors dominus, patiens et multum misericors. Poenitens etiam interdum dicitur, inquantum secundum aeternum et immutabilem providentiae suae ordinem facit quae prius destruxerat, vel destruit quae prius fecit: sicut et poenitentia moti facere inveniuntur. Unde Gen. 6-7: poenitet me fecisse hominem. Quod autem hoc proprie intelligi non possit, patet per hoc quod habetur I Reg. 15-29: triumphator in Israel non parcet, nec poenitudine flectetur. [54]

There is a subtle distinction between *clemens* and *misericors* which explains this statement: since *misericordia* appears to imply a certain *compassion* (literally "suffering with"), it is not seen as "properly" part of the divine attributes.

Words like *clementissimus* and *summe misericors* of course abound in more devotional contexts, but I suspect an *omni-* word is missing because that terminology is more properly philosophical/theological.